# $.tpl is not a function, $(".timepicker").timepickr is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, timepicker

Using jQuery timepickr: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-timepickr
Having included these files:

```
jquery-1.7.1.min.js
jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js
ui.timepickr.js
```

And getting this error. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are missing dependencies.

- jquery.utils.js
- jquery.strings.js
- jquery.ui.js

Written in its source-code. after license

Comment: Thanks! Also this helped: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/issues/detail?id=53 I grabbed "jquery.utils.js", "jquery.strings.js" and "ui.timepickr.js" from trunk and that made it work.

Answer (score 0):

If `$.fn.timepickr` isn't defined, make sure you aren't including another library that makes use of `$`, such as a second copy of jQuery.